# Convergence in measure of products

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(X,\mathcal A)$ and let $f, f_1, f_2,\dots$ and $g, g_1, g_2,\dots $be real valued $\mathcal A$- measureable functions on $X$.

Show that if $\mu$ is finite, $(f_n)$ convergence to $f$ in measure and $(g_n)$ to $g$ in measure, then $(f_ng_n)$ convergence to $fg$.
Can the assumption that $\mu$ is finite be omitted?

Intuitively it feels like one could look at the measure of the union where the convergence does not hold, for $f_n$ and $g_n$. Is that correct or what should I do?
And what about the finiteness of $\mu$?

Comment: Maybe a better way to think of it.  "Convergence in measure" may need an altered definition when $\mu$ is not finite.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Finiteness of $\mu$ is needed: take $f_n(x):=\frac 1n\chi_{(0,n)}$ and $g(x)=g_n(x)=x$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on the real line. Indeed, $f_n\to 0=:f$ in measure because for a fixed $\varepsilon$, for $n\gt 1/\varepsilon+1$, the set $\left\{x\in\mathbb R, \left\lvert f_n(x)\right\rvert\gt \varepsilon\right\}$ is empty. But it is not true that $f_ng_n\to 0$ in measure; for $\varepsilon=1/2$,
$$
\left\{x\in\mathbb R, \left\lvert (f_ng_n)(x)\right\rvert\gt 1/2\right\}
\supset \left(\frac n2,n\right).$$

When $\mu$ is finite, fix $\varepsilon>0$. There is $A>0$ such that $\mu\left\{|f|>A\right\}+\mu\left\{|g|>A\right\}<\varepsilon$.

Then write
$$\left\{|f_ng_n-fg|>2\delta^2\right\}\subset\left\{|f_n-f|\cdot |g_n|>\delta^2\right\}\cup\left\{|f|\cdot|g_n-g|>\delta^2\right\}.$$
We can intersect over $\left\{|f|<A\right\}\cap \left\{|g|<A\right\}$ (its complement has a small measure). More precisely, let $B:=\left\{|f|<A\right\}\cap \left\{|g|<A\right\}$. Then
$$\mu\left\{|f_ng_n-fg|>2\delta^2\right\}\leqslant \mu(B^c)+\mu(\left\{|f_n-f|\cdot |g_n|>\delta^2\right\}\cap B)+\mu(\{|f|\cdot|g_n-g|>\delta^2\}\cap B).$$
Since $\left\{|f|\cdot|g_n-g|>\delta^2\right\}\cap B\subset \left\{A\cdot |g_n-g|\gt\delta^2 \right\}\cap B\subset  \left\{A\cdot |g_n-g|\gt\delta^2 \right\}$, the third term is not problematic. For the second one, notice that
\begin{align}
\mu\left(\left\{\left|f_n-f\right|\cdot \left|g_n\right|>2\delta^2\right\}\cap B\right) &\leqslant\mu\left\{|f_n-f|\cdot |g_n-g|>\delta^2\right\}+\mu\left(\left\{\left|f_n-f\right|\cdot |g|>\delta^2\right\}\cap B\right)\\
&\leqslant \mu\{\left|f_n-f\right|>\delta\}+\mu\{|g_n-g|>\delta\}+\mu\left\{\left|f_n-f\right|>\delta^2/A\right\}.
\end{align}

Comment: Can you please expand a little?  and what do you mean with $\{\mu |f| > A \}$ I gues its $\mu \{x \in X : |f(x)| > A \}$? How do you get that inclusion with the $\delta$ and what does the intersection mean?

Comment: Yes, $\{|f|>A\}$ is the set of $x\in X$ for which $|f(x)|>A$. I've added details.

Comment: "When μ is finite, fix ε>0. There is A>0 such that μ{|f|>A}+μ{|g|>A}<ε." why is this true?

Comment: @mezhang Because the sequences $\{|f|>n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{|g|>n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ are nested, and have $0$ measure.

Comment: I meant "_their intersection_ have $0$ measure".

Comment: I don't see where you used the finiteness of the measure.

Comment: The $A$ may not exist if the measure space is not finite.

Comment: I am sorry for adding a comment on this old post but isn't an additional assumption that f and g are finite a.e needed here?

Comment: @TheHolyJoker I have added details on this part.

Comment: @Mathcho $f$ and $g$ are real-valued by hypothesis. (Commenting on your old comment on this old answer.) :-D

Comment: @mathnoob123 You are right. I have edited.

Comment: In the first term of the penultimate line, when showing that the second term is unproblematic, it should be $\mu(\{|f_n-f|\cdot|g_n| > \delta^2\}\cap B)$ instead of $> 2\delta^2$; at least if you want to stick with the same $\delta$.