# If $f_n$ $\longrightarrow$ $f$ in measure and $g_n$ $\longrightarrow$ $g$ in measure then show that $f_n +g_n$ $\longrightarrow$ $f+g$ in measure

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

(1)
If $f_n$ $\longrightarrow$ $f$ in measure and $g_n$ $\longrightarrow$ $g$ in measure then show that $f_n +g_n$ $\longrightarrow$ $f+g$ in measure

(2)If $f_n \longrightarrow \theta$ in measure and $g_n \longrightarrow \theta$ in measure where $\theta$ is the identically zero function on $\Omega$ then show that $f_ng_n \longrightarrow 0$

**My attempt**
For both cases I use the fact that $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ is my measure space where everything is defined in the H.L Royden.

For (1) it follows from the relation $ {x \in E |(f_n+g_n)(x)-(f+g)(x)}|\geq \epsilon$}

the above is a subset of the set $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq \epsilon/2$ obviously and thus is the

union of the set $|g_n(x)-g(x)|\geq \epsilon/2$ and hence the resukt holds.

Note here my measure is taken over an arbitrary set E. And this shows (1)

For (2) im drawing a blank and I don't have any idea how to even begin such a question. How do I 'handle' the zero function ?

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled about the title of your question. Since you already solved this part of the problem it would be more natural to to put the 2nd part in the title of your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints for (2):

1. Let $(h_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of measurable functions. Prove that $h_n \to 0$ in measure implies $h_n^2 \to 0$ in measure.
2. Use the first part of your problem and Step 1 to show that $(f_n+g_n)^2 \to 0$ in measure and $(f_n-g_n)^2 \to 0$ in measure.
3. Use $$f_n \cdot g_n = \frac{1}{4} \big( (f_n+g_n)^2- (f_n-g_n)^2 \big)$$ and Step 1 to conclude that $f_n \cdot g_n \to 0$ in measure.

Comment: Thanks very much this makes more sense to me now!

Comment: @JasonMoore You are welcome.

Comment: @saz Does it true that if $f_n\to f$ in measure and $g_n\to g$ in measure then $f_ng_n\to fg$ in measure?

Comment: @user726608 no, in general not... unless you have a finite measure space, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/456393/36150)