# Doubts in proof of product of sequnce of convergence in measure in finite measure also converges in measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[Convergence in measure of products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456393/convergence-in-measure-of-products)

I come across above question in which David Sir give proof of question .

But I am not able to understand [image]

I tried to understand form morning i think I got all except last line .

Actually I found above proof very constructive . Sorry But I am not able to intuition to prove theorem .

I really thankful if someone help me .

ANy help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $|f_n-f|.|g_n|>2\delta^2 \implies |f_n-f|.|g|>\delta^2 \ or \  |f_n-f|.|g_n-g|>2\delta^2$ by triangle inequality and hence we get

> $$\mu(\{|f_n-f|.|g_n|>2\delta^2\}\cap B)\leq\mu(\{|f_n-f|.|g_n-g|>\delta^2\}\cap B)+\mu(\{|f_n-f|.|g|>\delta^2\}\cap B)$$
>   $$\implies \mu(\{|f_n-f|.|g_n|>2\delta^2\}\cap B)\leq \mu(\{|f_n-f|.|g_n-g|>\delta^2\})+\mu(\{|f_n-f|.|g|>\delta^2\}\cap B)$$

where in the last inequality we have ignored the measurable set $B$ from the first summand.

Now $|f_n-f|.|g_n-g|>\delta^2 \implies |f_n-f|>\delta \ or \ |g_n-g|>\delta$ and hence we have $$\mu(\{|f_n-f|.|g_n-g|>\delta^2\})\leq\mu(|f_n-f|>\delta)+\mu(|g_n-g|>\delta)$$

For the second term we have $\{|f_n-f|.|g|>\delta^2\}\cap B \subset \{|f_n-f|.|g|>\delta^2\}\cap \{|g|<A \} \subset \{|f_n-f|>\frac{\delta^2}{A} \}$. Thus we have 
$$\mu(\{|f_n-f|.|g|>\delta^2\}\cap B)\leq\mu(\{|f_n-f|>\frac{\delta^2}{A} \})$$

Plugging all these back in our original inequality we get

> $$\mu(\{|f_n-f|.|g_n|>2\delta^2\}\cap B)\leq \mu(\{|f_n-f|.|g_n-g|>\delta^2\})+\mu(\{|f_n-f|.|g|>\delta^2\}\cap B)$$
>   $$\leq\mu(|f_n-f|>\delta)+\mu(|g_n-g|>\delta)+\mu(\{|f_n-f|>\frac{\delta^2}{A} \})$$.

This solves your problem because each summand individually goes to $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$